# Movimentos no tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou apendendo python, e quis fazer uma interface em que tenha uma bola que vá batendo nas paredes, só que queria saber como posso fazer pra bola ir batendo nas paredes.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
tela = Tk()
tela.geometry('500x500')
tela.resizable(False, False)

canvas = Canvas(tela, width=400, height=400, bg='black')
ball = canvas.create_oval(20,20,50,50, fill='red')
canvas.pack()
for x in range(60):
    y = x = 6
    canvas.move(ball, x, y)
    time.sleep(0.025)
    tela.update()
sair = Button(tela, text='Sair', bg='red', command=tela.destroy)
sair.pack()
tela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use `time.sleep()` pois sua interface fica irresponsiva.

Ao invés disso, crie uma função para atualizar a posição da bola, e use `tela.after()` para agendar a execução dessa função de tempos em tempos.

Dentro da função, use `canvas.coords()` para pegar as coordenadas da bola e ver se ela passou dos limites da tela (400x400 no seu caso). Se tiver passado, inverta a direção.

```
from tkinter import *
tela = Tk()
tela.geometry('500x500')
tela.resizable(False, False)

canvas = Canvas(tela, width=400, height=400, bg='black')
ball = canvas.create_oval(20,20,50,50, fill='red')
canvas.pack()
x = 6
y = 8

def atualiza_posicao_bola():
    global x, y
    canvas.move(ball, x, y)    
    xb, yb, xs, ys = canvas.coords(ball)
    if xs > 400 or xb < 0:
        x = -x  # inverte a direcao eixo x
    if ys > 400 or yb < 0:
        y = -y  # inverte a direcao eixo y
    tela.after(25, atualiza_posicao_bola) # agenda pra daqui a pouco

tela.after(0, atualiza_posicao_bola) # agendamento inicial
sair = Button(tela, text='Sair', bg='red', command=tela.destroy)
sair.pack()
tela.mainloop()
```

Veja que optei por manter a estrutura do código similar à sua para facilitar o entendimento. Em uma futura evolução desse código, sugiro usar uma classe para a bola, e armazenar as variáveis de direção como atributos dessa classe, evitando dessa forma o uso de globais e possibilitando mais flexibilidade como a criação de múltiplas bolas e/ou outros elementos.